# avoid overlap of geom points in R

Tags: r, plot, ggmap

I am plotting points on a map, with the following code

```
crime_poss_drugs$colorbucket<- as.numeric(cut(crime_poss_drugs$count,c(0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1100,Inf)))
crime_prod_drugs$colorbucket<- as.numeric(cut(crime_prod_drugs$count,c(0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1100,Inf)))
ggmap(Map) +
   geom_point(data = crime_poss_drugs,shape=22,
        aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour=factor(colorbucket)))+
   geom_point(data = crime_prod_drugs,
        aes(x = lon, y = lat,colour=factor(colorbucket)))
```

But the problem is, there are overlapping points from both the layers of geom_point(). Can any one please suggest me how to avoid overlapping in representation when they are at same latitude longitude position.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Would reducing the `alpha` help? This makes each point slightly transparent, so overlapping points appear darker than solitary ones. Try `geom_point(..., alpha = 3/8)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it kind of worked.Changed the shape to triangle and decreased the hue. Can you help how to change default colors after factor(colorbucket). Use different set of colors rather than the default. I am new to R

Comment: Look at `?scale_color_manual`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could explore many options with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the alpha value is a good suggestion.  One other option is to jitter the points, ie, add a bit of random noise so they do not collide as much. (This makes more sense in some contexts than others -- it's a substantive question, really.)  Check out [the geom_jitter docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_jitter.html) if you are curious.